# Alternative toif (elem.changed == 'true')

Tags: javascript

I think that `if (elem.changed == 'true')` is now incompatible with IE because since we did an Update to our server and now we work without Compatibility mode, this function isnt working since `elem.change` is now "undefined". What options can i do in a way that i dont have to modify my code alot?

```js
function gravatabela(numRegs, dia) {
  var params = '';
  url = '';

  for (k = 0; k < numRegs; k++) {
    url = '';
    vSend = true;
    elem = document.getElementById("tr" + k);
    if (elem.changed == 'true') {
      inputs = elem.getElementsByTagName("select");
      params = '?LINEID=' + k;
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i]) {
          params += '&' + inputs[i].name + '=' + inputs[i].value;

        }
      }

      inputs = elem.getElementsByTagName("span");
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i]) {
          params += '&' + inputs[i].name + '=' + inputs[i].innerText;

        }
      }

      inputs = elem.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i]) {
          if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            //alert(i);

            params += '&' + inputs[i].name + '=' + (inputs[i].checked ? "1" : "0");
            //alert(params);
          } else {
            if (inputs[i].juntadia) {
              if (inputs[i].value && inputs[i].value != '') {
                if (inputs[i].length == 0 || validaHorasStr(inputs[i].value))
                  params += '&' + inputs[i].name + '=' + inputs[i].juntadia + ' ' + inputs[i].value + ':00';
                else {
                  vCampo = '';
                  if (inputs[i].name == "EFEC_ENT")
                    vCampo = 'Hora de entrada (efectiva)';
                  if (inputs[i].name == "EFEC_SAI_ALM")
                    vCampo = 'Hora de saida para almoço (efectiva)';
                  if (inputs[i].name == "EFEC_REG_ALM")
                    vCampo = 'Hora de regresso de almoço (efectiva)';
                  if (inputs[i].name == "EFEC_SAIDA")
                    vCampo = 'Data de saída (efectiva)';
                  updatepage(k + '$KO$Erro nos dados a enviar: o campo ' + vCampo + ' não está correcto.');
                  vSend = false;
                }
              } else
                params += '&' + inputs[i].name + '=';

              //alert(inputs[i].juntadia + ' ' + inputs[i].value + ':00');
            } else
              params += '&' + inputs[i].name + '=' + inputs[i].value;

          }
        }
      }
      if (vSend) {
        url = 'grupo4_pantalla6_upd.jsp' + params;
        //alert(url);
        xmlhttpPost(url);
      }
      //alert(url);
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: @MilanChheda I'm sorry, but I don't think it is a good idea to make wholesale revisions to the coding style in a question, unless there is an actual problem such as not using four leading spaces to trigger code formatting. I agree with you that the curly brace on the same line is an improvement, but I don't agree that reducing the indentation to two spaces is an improvement. You also didn't fix other more important style issues such as the use of curly braces in one branch of an `if` but no curly braces in the other.

Comment: If you think there are code formatting changes that would improve the code in a question, it would be better to post your suggested changes as an answer. (Yes, it's OK to post an "answer" that doesn't actually answer the specific question but suggests other ways the code could be improved.) By posting your changes as an answer, the OP and other readers would be able to compare the original style with your suggestion and see how you have improved the code. So would you please consider reverting your edit and posting your suggestions as an answer instead? I'll give you an upvote if you do. ;-)

Comment: Sure @MichaelGeary. I will consider your points in henceforth edits. In this particular case, code was not styled and wasn't readable. Hence, I just used `Tidy` and made it styled.

Comment: Ah, I see. It sounds like Tidy could use some improvements itself then. I can live with different indentation and brace styles, but I think it's a really bad practice to not use braces on both the `if` and `else` as in code like `if( condition ) { foo(); } else bar();`. A really good code formatter would clean this up too. (This was wasn't a problem that your edit introduced; it was just carried over from the original code.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `onChange` event in HTML like this:

`<select onchange="myFunction()">`

Even so jQuery is compatible with all browsers.

Comment: this is where the function is called in html:  <div class="submit">
      <a class="tooltip to-right" href="javascript:gravatabela(<%=zcounti%>);"><span class="left-side">Enviar</span></a>
     </div>
    <% } else { %>
     <span style="color:RED">Não se podem alterar registos anteriores ao dia 16 do último mês.</span>
    <% } %>